# why redis runs in sentinel mode by default?

Tags: redis

Why does redis run in sentinel mode by default and just can't be used as usual?
it's `windows version-3.2.1` I just changed the port to `6387`

then redisted as service:

> .\redis-server.exe --service-install redis.windows-service.conf
>   --Service-name redis6387 --loglevel verbose

Started it  and try "set"、"get" orders
it came out a error info:

> (error) ERR unknown command 'set'

at the same time, the server_log.txt shows:

> [14184] 25 Apr 09:34:03.159 * Redis 3.2.100 (00000000/0) 64 bit,
>   sentinel mode, port 6387, pid 14184 ready to start. [14184] 25 Apr
>   09:34:03.161 # Sentinel ID is fd060bfccf816affb900a2c2402eecb58163273c

by the way, I had a redis-cluster in this same win-computer.the `redis-trib.rb` can be considered as a factor.

Answer (score 0):

[change the directory-name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1wRU.png)

if you put the redis in such file.it runs in sentinel mode anyway。。。。
all you need to do is just change the directoryName